# gphoto2 /FFmpeg: Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?):

Tags: video, webcam, ffmpeg, gphoto2

First question here as I have been finding answers to everything else I had issues with previously, thanks to all who contribute here..

I followed this guide to use gphoto2 and ffmpeg to use my Fuji X-T2 live feed as a webcam:

https://medium.com/nerdery/dslr-webcam-setup-for-linux-9b6d1b79ae22

it works well when I first start the machine and turn on the camera:

```
 $ pkill -f gphoto2
```

> (unmount camera as volume)

```
 $ gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video0
    ffmpeg version 4.4-6ubuntu5 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu1)
      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=6ubuntu5 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
      libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
      libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
      libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
      libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
      libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
      libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
      libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
      libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
    Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
    [mjpeg @ 0x55b4c5b39340] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
    Input #0, mjpeg, from 'pipe:':
      Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
      Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1024x768, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> rawvideo (native))
    [swscaler @ 0x55b4c5b8c800] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
    Output #0, video4linux2,v4l2, to '/dev/video0':
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
      Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1024x768, q=2-31, 235929 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 rawvideo
    frame=  444 fps= 32 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:17.76 bitrate=N/A speed=1.29x
```

However if I switch off the camera and try to run again later in the day I eventually get the error message below:

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video0
ffmpeg version 4.4-6ubuntu5 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=6ubuntu5 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
[mjpeg @ 0x5635c5ca0340] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1024x768, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> rawvideo (native))
[swscaler @ 0x5635c5cfc600] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x5635c5ca4080] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

Only solution I have currently is to reboot the desktop - any ideas on how to fix / troubleshoot pls?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Version = 21.10

Comment: https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/247 - seems it could be related to the kernel and v4l2 after further digging.

Comment: fix to avoid reboot before a proper fix:

sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 max_buffers=2